# A-frame light doesnt effect object

Tags: three.js, aframe, webvr

I am working on a scene in A-frame and I'm wondering how I can create an object that light doesnt effect. This means that no matter what lighting my scene has, this object wont be impacted by the lighting and will have default lighting. How can this be done?

Comment: Do you mind explaining in more detail what you mean with "default lighting"?

Comment: By default lighting I mean no lighting whatsoever. Just like in the default A-frame boilerplate when you havent added any lighting there will just be no lighting in my scene. I want all lighting not to impact a certain object.

Comment: `three.js` does no support selective lighting. So when you add a light to your scene, all 3D objects with lit materials are potentially being affected.